# Invalid IV length error when decrypting cookie after upgrade node to 6.10.1

Tags: node.js, encryption

Hi i'm working on some code which was decrypting cookie generated by some .NET application

```
function hex2a(hex) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    return str;
}

//Raw cookie
var cookie = "B417B464CA63FE780584563D2DA4709B03F6195189044C26A29770F3203881DD90B1428139088D945CF6807CA408F201DABBADD59CE1D740F853A894692273F1CA83EC3F26493744E3D25D720374E03393F71E21BE2D96B6110CB7AC12E44447FFBD810D3D57FBACA8DF5249EB503C3DFD255692409F084650EFED205388DD8C08BF7B941E1AC1B3B70B9A8E09118D756BEAFF25834E72357FD40E80E76458091224FAE8";

//decryptionKey from issuers <machineKey>
var deckey = "FFA87B82D4A1BEAA15C06F6434A7EB2251976A838784E134900E6629B9F954B7";


var crypto = require('crypto');

var ivc = cookie, iv, cipherText, ivSize = 16, res = "";

ivc = new Buffer(ivc, 'hex');
iv = new Buffer(ivSize);
cipherText = new Buffer(ivc.length - ivSize);
ivc.copy(iv, 0, 0, ivSize);
ivc.copy(cipherText, 0, ivSize);

c = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', hex2a(deckey), iv.toString('binary'));
res = c.update(cipherText, "binary", "utf8");
```

code was running on 5.9.0 node, but stopped to run after upgrading to 6.10.1

the error message i'm getting is "Invalid IV length".

please help

Thanks forwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some changes made to `crypto` in Node v6, in particular regarding to default encodings.

Try this:

```
c = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(deckey, 'hex'), iv);
```